# TControlClass as generic TControl parameter?

Tags: delphi, generics

I have class `TLuaClassTemplate<T: TControl, constructor> = class` and trying to use it's method `class procedure RegisterClass(L: Plua_State; p: TPrintProc; container: TComponent; vm: TLuaVm); static;` with TControlClass references stored in TDictionary

```
  TClassNameToComponentDict = TDictionary<string, TControlClass>;
  TClassNameToComponentPair = TPair<string, TControlClass>;

...
  ClassNameToComponent := TClassNameToComponentDict.Create;
  ClassNameToComponent.Add('TButton', TButton);
  ClassNameToComponent.Add('TPanel', TPanel);
  ClassNameToComponent.Add('TEdit', TEdit);
```

But I have problem on attempt to use it

```
  enum: TClassNameToComponentPair;
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  cls: TControlClass;
begin
  for enum in vm.ClassNameToComponent do begin
    //TLuaClassTemplate<enum.Value>.RegisterClass(vm.LS, PrintGlobal, container, vm);
    cls := TControlClass((ctx.FindType(enum.Key) as TRttiInstanceType).MetaClassType);
    TLuaClassTemplate<cls>.RegisterClass(vm.LS, PrintGlobal, container, vm);
  end;
```

I've tried both current visible (found by searching) and commented options. But error is `Undeclared identifier: 'TLuaClassTemplate'` while `TLuaClassTemplate<TButton>.RegisterClass(vm.LS, PrintGlobal, container, vm);` works.

How can I use TControlClass as generic parameter here?

Comment: Thank, and keep asking the good questions. I keep voting them up because they are well asked and interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue that you have is that instantiation of a generic requires that the type arguments are known at compile time. In your code `cls` is not known at compile time, it is only determined at runtime. And that means that `TLuaClassTemplate<cls>` is an invalid instantiation of the generic.

The bottom line here is that generics give you parameterisation of your code, but the parameters must be supplied at compile time. Since you don't know the parameters until runtime, you cannot solve your problem using generics.

Well, I say, cannot, but you could use RTTI to call your generic method. For that to work you'd need to ensure that each possible instantiated type was included in the executable's list of types. But doing all that would really defeat the purposes of generics! It's going to be much easier to use standard runtime arguments rather than compile time generic arguments.